# iPhone: Drag&Drop UIViews

Tags: iphone, uiview, drag-and-drop

[image]

That is what I suppose to have. UIViewController with a dynamic number of draggable UIViews.
The cases that should be covered is:

1. When user start to drag and than in some moment take his finger off, if UIView is in "place to drop" area than it should be there, if not, then it should be turned back where it was.

   2.If user draged UIView3 to " place to drop", Than UIView4 should relocate on place UIView3.

Is there any tutorials how to implement that ?

Have u any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check the [DragKit](http://dragkit.org/). It's open source, so you may explore the logic and technic too.

As your views seems to be placed in grid, you may also check the [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView). Also an open source project, BTW. And it contains the Drag'n'Drop example.